# WPF new item goes behind everything

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridlines

I have a window and I aligned and set everything but now I want to add some `Line`-s or `LineGeometry`-es to this window. If I don't drag and drop something from the toolbox just declare it in code or xaml my lines created behind the grid or everything inspite of where I do it. When I slide my left gridline the new line appears like the gridlines cover it. If I recreate the gridlines everything is messed up and I don't want to start over the window

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what you're describing, could you include the code for your line, and perhaps a screenshot of the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: http://imgur.com/S3wflgL,04T296A
I uploaded two pictures to show what happens when the gridline is slided.

Comment: What's the z index in your xaml?

Comment: Everything's z index is 0. But it wasn't a problem before. I drew and placed a lot of things to the window and today I opened the vstudio and that's happens

Comment: You want to actually set the Z index higher than your old items for it to be on top.

Comment: @lll
I set the z index of the new item to 99 and the problem still occurs

Comment: Make sure the `Container` is a `Panel` or else it wont work.

Comment: @lll it's a `Grid` in xaml and `Canvas` in code (xaml is just for check in the designer)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a copy of my project and inserted the code and there, it works fine inspite of they are copies of each other. (I don't get it why)